# Why occurred plotly x-axis data sorting problem?

Tags: javascript, html, razor, plotly

First, Please see the picture below...

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/760yR.png)

I want to display plotly chart monthly.
i set x axis data after sorting by month.
but chart x-axis shows like picture above...

how to fix it..?

below is the associated source code.
(key.Month is already sorting by ascendig.)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var xData = @Html.Raw(@Model.MonthlyChartdata.XData);
    var yData = @Html.Raw(@Model.MonthlyChartdata.YData);
    var labels = @Html.Raw(@Model.MonthlyChartdata.Labels);

    var data = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < xData.length; i++) {
        var result = {
            x: xData[i],
            y: yData[i],
            name: labels[i],
            type: 'line'
        };
        data.push(result);
    }

    Plotly.newPlot('MonthlyAlarmCountChart', data, layout);
});



    private void CreateChartDataGroupByMonth()
    {
        MonthlyChartdata = new ChartData();

        //Type
        List<string> labels = new List<string>();
        //Period
        List<int[][]> xDatas = new List<int[][]>();
        //Amount
        List<int[]> yDatas = new List<int[]>();

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<Period, int>> kvp in MonthlyAlarmCount)
        {
            List<int[]> xDataPeriod = new List<int[]>();
            List<int> xDataYear = new List<int>();
            List<int> xDataMonth = new List<int>();
            List<int> yData = new List<int>();

            //Type
            labels.Add(kvp.Key);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<Period, int> kvp2 in kvp.Value)
            {
                //Year
                xDataYear.Add(kvp2.Key.Year);
                //Month
                xDataMonth.Add(kvp2.Key.Month);
                //Count
                yData.Add(kvp2.Value);
            }

            xDataPeriod.Add(xDataYear.ToArray());
            xDataPeriod.Add(xDataMonth.ToArray());

            xDatas.Add(xDataPeriod.ToArray());
            yDatas.Add(yData.ToArray());
        }

        MonthlyChartdata.Labels = JsonSerializer.Serialize(labels.ToArray());
        MonthlyChartdata.XData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(xDatas.ToArray());
        MonthlyChartdata.YData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(yDatas.ToArray());
    }
```